# Where do I initialize backgrid in my Backbone/Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, backgrid

I have a Backbone.js app and am trying to integrate with Backgrid, but I am having trouble understanding where I should be calling `new Backgrid`. I tried calling it in my view after things get rendered but appending the grid doesn't work because things aren't *actually* rendered yet. Here is some code:

#### SpreadsheetIndex.js.coffee

```
D3.Views.SpreadsheetsIndex = Support.CompositeView.extend
  initialize: (options) ->
    this.tables = options.tables
    this.resources = options.resources
    _.bindAll(this, 'render')

  render: ->
    this.renderTemplate()
    this.renderSpreadsheets()

    resources = this.resources

    this.tables.each (table) ->

      subset = resources.subcollection
        filter: (resource) -> 
          resource.escape('table_id') == table.escape('id')

      grid = new Backgrid.Grid
        columns: table.attributes.columns
        collection: subset

      $("#"+table.escape('id')).append(grid.render().$el);
    return this

  renderTemplate: ->
    this.$el.html(JST['spreadsheets/index']({ spreadsheets: this.tables }))

  renderSpreadsheets: ->
    self = this
    self.$('tbody').empty();
```

#### spreadsheets/index.jst.ejs

```
<% spreadsheets.each(function(spreadsheet) { %>
  <h4><%= spreadsheet.escape('name')%></h4>
  <div id='<%= spreadsheet.escape('id') %>'></div>
<% }) %>
```

The issue is that the `$("#"+table.escape('id'))` selector does not select anything because the template hasn't rendered yet. It feels like I'm putting this in the wrong place. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that you want to use the view's [`@$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) method to instead of `$` to localize the selector to the view's `el`:

```
this.tables.each (table) =>
  #...
  @$("#"+table.escape('id')).append(grid.render().$el);
```

Note that `->` has become `=>` (to get the right `@`/`this`) and it now uses `@$` instead of `$`.

---

While I'm here, you can do a couple other things to make your code more ideomatic:

1. Say `class D3.Views.SpreadsheetsIndex extends Support.CompositeView` instead of the JavaScripty `D3.Views.SpreadsheetsIndex = Support.CompositeView.extend`.
2. Use `@` instead of `this`, for example `@tables = options.table` rather than `this.tables = options.table`.
3. You can use string interpolation instead of `+` if you think it is cleaner:

   ```
   @$("##{table.escape('id')}")
   ```
4. You rarely need `bindAll`, instead of `_.bindAll(this, 'render')` you could define `render` as `render: =>` to get the binding to happen automatically.
5. You rarely need the `var self = this` trick in CoffeeScript, you can usually use a `=>` instead. And you don't need either one here:

   ```
   renderSpreadsheets: ->
     self = this
     self.$('tbody').empty();
   ```

   you can just `renderSpreadsheets: -> @$('tbody').empty()`

Comment: @chapmand: I added a few other pointers that you might be interested in.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tips. I'm pretty new to Coffeescript and Backbone so that's very helpful.